# How can I backup the Windows Web Credentials store?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, credentials-manager

I have just purchased a new PC and even though I'm using Windows 10 with a MS account & Password sync enabled, it seems like no Passwords were synced on the new PC.

On my old PC I have stored a lot of Login Details with MS Edge / IE over the past years and they would always show up in the Windows credentials Manager under "Web credentials". I tried to use the backup & restore feature there but it only backs up the Windows credentials, not the Web credentials.

How can I Transfer the web credentials to my new PC?

Just for reference: Here's a Picture of the [Windows web credentials store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YReS.png) on my new PC which only contains new entries from the past 24 Hours of usage. My old PC contains probably about 100 entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the Credentials manager in Control Panel. There are at least two other ways to access your credentials:

a command line program:

```
cmdkey.exe
```

and an alternative GUI:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

in the last one, backing up the credentials and restoring them works for me, including the web credentials.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get the command line program to even see the web credentials, but the alternative GUI method seems to have worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell

```
[void]
[Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
$vault = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault
$vault.RetrieveAll() | % { $_.RetrievePassword();$_ }
```

and copy paste technology to notepad :)

Answer (score 0):

We can try to use a reliable third-party software called **VaultPasswordView** from NirSoft.

VaultPasswordView is a new utility from the trusted NirSoft to help users decrypt and view passwords and other data saved in Windows Vault. Passwords of Internet Explorer as well as Microsoft Edge are saved in Windows Vault.

For details we can refer to： [Backup Or Export Passwords From Edge In Windows 10](https://www.intowindows.com/backup-or-export-passwords-from-edge-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of the Chromium Based Edge, this is easy

1. Install a fresh copy of the new (Chromium-based) Edge, this will migrate all Legacy Edge Web Credentials into the new Edge browser.
   (You should be always able to install a fresh copy yourself manually - if you have already a version installed. You would only need to take extra steps if you still used the legacy IE/Edge in parallel; an update of the new Edge browser might be sufficient, or a reinstall as a worst case).
2. Then, open the new Edge Preferences, go to passwords, and there you will find an `...` options button on the top left that allows you to export your passwords to an (unprotected) CSV file after you have provided your Windows credentials.